# StoreKit Framework for Android

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Is there a similar solution for in-app play-store,

Just like StoreKit Framework iOS provides?

*I saw that YouTube sometimes open the playstore in a pop-up window.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check [In-app Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html):

> In-app Billing is a Google Play service that lets you sell digital content from inside your applications. You can use the service to sell a wide range of content, including downloadable content such as media files or photos, virtual content such as game levels or potions, premium services and features, and more.

---

## Implementing In-app Billing

> In-app Billing on Google Play provides a straightforward, simple interface for sending In-app Billing requests and managing In-app Billing transactions using Google Play. The information below covers the basics of how to make calls from your application to the In-app Billing service using the [Version 3 API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html).

To implement In-app Billing in your application, you need to do the following:

1. Add the In-app Billing library to your project.
2. Update your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.
3. Create a `ServiceConnection` and bind it to `IInAppBillingService`.
4. Send In-app Billing requests from your application to `IInAppBillingService`.
5. Handle In-app Billing responses from Google Play.

App's Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

Creating a ServiceConnection

```
IInAppBillingService mService;

ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
@Override
public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
mService = null;
}

@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name,
IBinder service) {
mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
}
};
```

For the complete implementation follow the [*tutorial*](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-permission) for Implementing the API.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. will it open a free app page, like: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ow1dt.jpg

Comment: No, doesn't look like it